# Powershell: String variable not a valid hex string error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script that pulls out the thumbprint of a certificate on a windows server so that I can use this thumbprint in a variable to use it in another command that creates a HTTPS listener.

I have managed to create the first step that works with the following command:

```
$thumbprint = (get-childitem -path cert:\localmachine\my | where-object {$_.subject -match $hostname+".xxx.com"}).thumbprint
```

So now i have the thumbprint saved in a variable.

Then i am trying to use the following command that works if i type in the contents of the $thumbprint value manually:

```
winrm create winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="$hostname";CertificateThumbprint="$thumbprint"}'
```

When running this command I get the following error:

```
Message = The WS-Management service cannot process the configuration request because the certificate thumbprint in the request is not a valid hex string: $thumbprint.
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this?

This works (manually typing the same value):

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="xxx.xxx.xxx";CertificateThumbprint="AF1D0F82070C4E3692BBF43747BAE74DED74A40A"}'
```

The contents of the `$thumbprint` variable is `AF1D0F82070C4E3692BBF43747BAE74DED74A40A`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using PowerShell, you can use `WSMan` PowerShell provider to configure WS-Management service:

```
New-Item WSMan:\localhost\Listener -Address * -Transport HTTPS -HostName $hostname -CertificateThumbPrint $thumbprint
```

Comment: Perfect @PetSerAl - always a good idea to solve a problem with a different approach. Works like a charm. In total i ended up using: winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS $hostname = (gc env:computername)+".domain.net" $thumbprint = (get-childitem -path cert:\localmachine\my | where-object {$_.subject -match $hostname}).thumbprint New-Item WSMan:\localhost\Listener -Address * -Transport HTTPS -HostName $Hostname -CertificateThumbprint $thumbprint

Comment: @lazerpld this worked for me. I added the -Force:$true argument to the New-Item command

Answer (score 1):

Since the `@{}` part is enclosed by single-quotes, PowerShell won't expand variables like `$thumbprint`, so instead of passing the thumbprint to `winrm`, you're passing the literal value `$thumbprint`.

You can use the `-f` operator to replace a placeholder inside a single-quoted string. Placeholders are numbered and enclosed by curly brackets, so you need to escape the `@{}` brackets as well:

```
$WinRMConfig = '@{{Hostname="$hostname";CertificateThumbprint="{0}"}}' -f $thumbprint
winrm create winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS $WinRMConfig
```

Comment: Hi Mathias,
Thanks for a very fast reply.

I have tried:

$WinRMConfig = '@{Hostname="xxx.xxx.xxx";CertificateThumbPrint="{0}"}' -f $thumbprint

But i get the following error:

Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format..
At line:1 char:74
+ $WinRMConfig = '@{Hostname="xxx.xxx.xxx";CertificateThumbPrint="{0}"}' -f <<<<  $thumbprint
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (AF1D0F82070C4E3692BBF43747BAE74DED74A40A:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError

Comment: @lazerpld sorry, forgot to escape the enclosing curly brackets, updated answer